# Error While running the Energy Plus agent in Volttron env

Tags: volttron, energyplus

I am attempting to run `Energy plus agent` but while running the agent I am getting the following error.

`ERROR: /bin/sh: 1: energyplus: Exec format error`

I followed the readme file in https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/tree/main/examples/EnergyPlusAgent

-
Steps I followed ---

1. Installed Eplus Agent

`wget https://github.com/NREL/EnergyPlus/releases/download/v8.5.0/EnergyPlus-8.5.0-c87e61b44b-Linux-x86_64.sh chmod +x EnergyPlus-8.5.0-c87e61b44b-Linux-x86_64.sh sudo ./EnergyPlus-8.5.0-c87e61b44b-Linux-x86_64.sh`

2. Copied 'bcvtb' and 'eplus' folders into root of VOLTTRON
3. Updated the configuration to reflect the correct address in configuration (yml) file.
4. started VOLTTRON
   ./start-volttron
5. Started EnergyPlus simulation example agent
   source env/bin/activate
   python scripts/install-agent.py -s examples/EnergyPlusAgent/ -c examples/EnergyPlusAgent/ep_building1.yml -i platform.actuator --tag eplus --start --force

Then I got the error

[image]

---

Logs

```
....
2021-06-21 17:42:02,066 () volttron.platform.agent.utils DEBUG: value from env False
2021-06-21 17:42:04,108 () root DEBUG: Creating ZMQ Core config.store
2021-06-21 17:42:04,126 () volttron.platform.store INFO: Initializing configuration store service.
2021-06-21 17:42:04,137 () root DEBUG: Creating ZMQ Core platform.auth
2021-06-21 17:42:04,158 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: loading auth file /home/pi/.volttron/auth.json
2021-06-21 17:42:04,165 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: auth file /home/pi/.volttron/auth.json loaded
2021-06-21 17:42:04,170 () volttron.platform.agent.utils INFO: Adding file watch for /home/pi/.volttron/auth.json dirname=/home/pi/.volttron, filename=auth.json
2021-06-21 17:42:04,174 () volttron.platform.agent.utils INFO: Added file watch for /home/pi/.volttron/auth.json
2021-06-21 17:42:04,175 () volttron.platform.agent.utils INFO: Adding file watch for /home/pi/.volttron/protected_topics.json dirname=/home/pi/.volttron, filename=protected_topics.json
2021-06-21 17:42:04,178 () volttron.platform.agent.utils INFO: Added file watch for /home/pi/.volttron/protected_topics.json
2021-06-21 17:42:04,182 () volttron.platform.vip.pubsubservice INFO: protected-topics loaded
2021-06-21 17:42:04,189 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core INFO: Connected to platform: router: d6df7a99-8bdc-4baa-8365-99e850fc31ee version: 1.0 identity: config.store
2021-06-21 17:42:04,308 () root DEBUG: Creating ZMQ Core control
2021-06-21 17:42:04,318 () root DEBUG: Creating ZMQ Core keydiscovery
2021-06-21 17:42:04,330 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: loading auth file /home/pi/.volttron/auth.json
2021-06-21 17:42:04,334 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core INFO: Connected to platform: router: d6df7a99-8bdc-4baa-8365-99e850fc31ee version: 1.0 identity: platform.auth
2021-06-21 17:42:04,342 () volttron.platform.vip.pubsubservice INFO: protected-topics loaded
2021-06-21 17:42:04,352 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.subsystems.configstore DEBUG: Processing callbacks for affected files: {}
2021-06-21 17:42:06,351 () root DEBUG: Creating ZMQ Core platform.health
2021-06-21 17:42:06,395 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core INFO: Connected to platform: router: d6df7a99-8bdc-4baa-8365-99e850fc31ee version: 1.0 identity: control
2021-06-21 17:42:06,410 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core INFO: Connected to platform: router: d6df7a99-8bdc-4baa-8365-99e850fc31ee version: 1.0 identity: keydiscovery
2021-06-21 17:42:06,424 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core INFO: Connected to platform: router: d6df7a99-8bdc-4baa-8365-99e850fc31ee version: 1.0 identity: platform.health
2021-06-21 17:42:06,850 () volttron.platform.auth WARNING: Attempt 1 to get peerlist failed with exception 0.5 seconds
2021-06-21 17:42:06,851 () volttron.platform.auth WARNING: Get list of peers from subsystem directly
2021-06-21 17:42:06,859 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: auth file /home/pi/.volttron/auth.json loaded
2021-06-21 17:42:06,862 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: loading auth file /home/pi/.volttron/auth.json
2021-06-21 17:42:09,378 () volttron.platform.auth WARNING: Attempt 1 to get peerlist failed with exception 0.5 seconds
2021-06-21 17:42:09,383 () volttron.platform.auth WARNING: Get list of peers from subsystem directly
2021-06-21 17:42:09,392 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: auth file /home/pi/.volttron/auth.json loaded
2021-06-21 17:42:09,395 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: loading auth file /home/pi/.volttron/auth.json
2021-06-21 17:42:11,912 () volttron.platform.auth WARNING: Attempt 1 to get peerlist failed with exception 0.5 seconds
2021-06-21 17:42:11,912 () volttron.platform.auth WARNING: Get list of peers from subsystem directly
2021-06-21 17:42:11,919 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: auth file /home/pi/.volttron/auth.json loaded
2021-06-21 17:42:11,921 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: loading auth file /home/pi/.volttron/auth.json
2021-06-21 17:42:14,441 () volttron.platform.auth WARNING: Attempt 1 to get peerlist failed with exception 0.5 seconds
2021-06-21 17:42:14,442 () volttron.platform.auth WARNING: Get list of peers from subsystem directly
2021-06-21 17:42:14,456 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: auth file /home/pi/.volttron/auth.json loaded
2021-06-21 17:44:50,027 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: AUTH: After authenticate user id: control.connection, b'd6df7a99-8bdc-4baa-8365-99e850fc31ee'
2021-06-21 17:44:50,027 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: authentication success: userid=b'd6df7a99-8bdc-4baa-8365-99e850fc31ee' domain='vip', address='localhost:1000:1000:2014', mechanism='CURVE', credentials=['ovpetUz6u_RkmcH433-2z37iZldQeWMU_F_SbLv1UGI'], user='control.connection'
2021-06-21 17:44:56,912 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: AUTH: After authenticate user id: control.connection, b'd6df7a99-8bdc-4baa-8365-99e850fc31ee'
2021-06-21 17:44:56,912 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: authentication success: userid=b'd6df7a99-8bdc-4baa-8365-99e850fc31ee' domain='vip', address='localhost:1000:1000:2027', mechanism='CURVE', credentials=['ovpetUz6u_RkmcH433-2z37iZldQeWMU_F_SbLv1UGI'], user='control.connection'
2021-06-21 17:44:57,039 () volttron.platform.aip DEBUG: Using name template "platform.actuator" to generate VIP ID
2021-06-21 17:44:57,040 () volttron.platform.aip INFO: Agent ff2eba4a-0743-4fa8-ad2f-c3fc00cc792f setup to use VIP ID platform.actuator
2021-06-21 17:44:57,041 () volttron.platform.aip DEBUG: IDENTITY_TEMPLATE file removed.
2021-06-21 17:44:57,041 () volttron.platform.agent.utils DEBUG: missing file /home/pi/.volttron/agents/ff2eba4a-0743-4fa8-ad2f-c3fc00cc792f/energyplusagent-0.1/energyplusagent-0.1.dist-info/keystore.json
2021-06-21 17:44:57,041 () volttron.platform.agent.utils INFO: creating file /home/pi/.volttron/agents/ff2eba4a-0743-4fa8-ad2f-c3fc00cc792f/energyplusagent-0.1/energyplusagent-0.1.dist-info/keystore.json
2021-06-21 17:44:57,042 () volttron.platform.keystore DEBUG: calling generate from keystore
2021-06-21 17:44:57,055 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: loading auth file /home/pi/.volttron/auth.json
2021-06-21 17:44:59,561 () volttron.platform.auth WARNING: Attempt 1 to get peerlist failed with exception 0.5 seconds
2021-06-21 17:44:59,562 () volttron.platform.auth WARNING: Get list of peers from subsystem directly
2021-06-21 17:44:59,566 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: auth file /home/pi/.volttron/auth.json loaded
2021-06-21 17:44:59,566 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: loading auth file /home/pi/.volttron/auth.json
2021-06-21 17:45:00,158 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: AUTH: After authenticate user id: control.connection, b'd6df7a99-8bdc-4baa-8365-99e850fc31ee'
2021-06-21 17:45:00,158 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: authentication success: userid=b'd6df7a99-8bdc-4baa-8365-99e850fc31ee' domain='vip', address='localhost:1000:1000:2034', mechanism='CURVE', credentials=['ovpetUz6u_RkmcH433-2z37iZldQeWMU_F_SbLv1UGI'], user='control.connection'
2021-06-21 17:45:00,279 () volttron.platform.aip INFO: starting agent /home/pi/.volttron/agents/ff2eba4a-0743-4fa8-ad2f-c3fc00cc792f/energyplusagent-0.1
2021-06-21 17:45:00,280 () volttron.platform.aip INFO: starting agent using <class 'volttron.platform.aip.ExecutionEnvironment'> 
2021-06-21 17:45:00,298 () volttron.platform.aip INFO: agent /home/pi/.volttron/agents/ff2eba4a-0743-4fa8-ad2f-c3fc00cc792f/energyplusagent-0.1 has PID 2042
2021-06-21 17:45:01,777 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ DEBUG: CONFIG PATH: /home/pi/.volttron/agents/ff2eba4a-0743-4fa8-ad2f-c3fc00cc792f/energyplusagent-0.1/energyplusagent-0.1.dist-info/config
2021-06-21 17:45:02,080 () volttron.platform.auth WARNING: Attempt 1 to get peerlist failed with exception 0.5 seconds
2021-06-21 17:45:02,080 () volttron.platform.auth WARNING: Get list of peers from subsystem directly
2021-06-21 17:45:02,084 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: auth file /home/pi/.volttron/auth.json loaded
2021-06-21 17:45:02,085 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: loading auth file /home/pi/.volttron/auth.json
2021-06-21 17:45:02,835 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) root DEBUG: Creating ZMQ Core platform.actuator
2021-06-21 17:45:02,843 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ DEBUG: vip_identity: platform.actuator
2021-06-21 17:45:02,926 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: AUTH: After authenticate user id: platform.actuator, b'd6df7a99-8bdc-4baa-8365-99e850fc31ee'
2021-06-21 17:45:02,927 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: authentication success: userid=b'd6df7a99-8bdc-4baa-8365-99e850fc31ee' domain='vip', address='localhost:1000:1000:2042', mechanism='CURVE', credentials=['lmK75j_D9UE5q4j_-Nbo55w3ZL1wQvYo3JRBAPNYN2o'], user='platform.actuator'
2021-06-21 17:45:02,936 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) volttron.platform.vip.agent.core INFO: Connected to platform: router: d6df7a99-8bdc-4baa-8365-99e850fc31ee version: 1.0 identity: platform.actuator
2021-06-21 17:45:02,992 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU1/VAV102
2021-06-21 17:45:02,993 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU1/VAV118
2021-06-21 17:45:02,993 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU1/VAV119
2021-06-21 17:45:02,993 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU1/VAV120
2021-06-21 17:45:02,993 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU1/VAV123A
2021-06-21 17:45:02,994 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU1/VAV123B
2021-06-21 17:45:02,994 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU1/VAV127A
2021-06-21 17:45:02,994 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU1/VAV127B
2021-06-21 17:45:02,994 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU1/VAV129
2021-06-21 17:45:02,994 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU1/VAV131
2021-06-21 17:45:02,994 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU1/VAV133
2021-06-21 17:45:02,995 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU1/VAV136
2021-06-21 17:45:02,995 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU1/VAV142
2021-06-21 17:45:02,995 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU1/VAV143
2021-06-21 17:45:02,995 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU1/VAV150
2021-06-21 17:45:02,995 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU1/VAV100
2021-06-21 17:45:02,996 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU1/VAV121
2021-06-21 17:45:02,996 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU3/VAV104
2021-06-21 17:45:02,996 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU3/VAV105
2021-06-21 17:45:02,997 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU3/VAV107
2021-06-21 17:45:02,997 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU3/VAV108
2021-06-21 17:45:02,997 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU3/VAV112
2021-06-21 17:45:02,997 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU3/VAV116
2021-06-21 17:45:02,997 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU2
2021-06-21 17:45:02,998 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/AHU4
2021-06-21 17:45:02,998 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE102
2021-06-21 17:45:02,998 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE104
2021-06-21 17:45:02,998 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE105
2021-06-21 17:45:02,998 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE107
2021-06-21 17:45:02,998 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE108
2021-06-21 17:45:02,999 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE112
2021-06-21 17:45:02,999 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE116
2021-06-21 17:45:02,999 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE118
2021-06-21 17:45:02,999 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE119
2021-06-21 17:45:02,999 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE120
2021-06-21 17:45:02,999 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE123A
2021-06-21 17:45:03,000 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE123B
2021-06-21 17:45:03,000 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE127A
2021-06-21 17:45:03,000 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE127B
2021-06-21 17:45:03,000 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE129
2021-06-21 17:45:03,000 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE131
2021-06-21 17:45:03,000 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE133
2021-06-21 17:45:03,001 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE142
2021-06-21 17:45:03,001 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE143
2021-06-21 17:45:03,001 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE150
2021-06-21 17:45:03,001 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) __main__ INFO: subscribed to PNNL/BUILDING1/LIGHTING/ZONE136
2021-06-21 17:45:03,002 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) integrations.energyplus_integration DEBUG: Bound to 46955 on '127.0.0.1'
2021-06-21 17:45:03,002 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) integrations.energyplus_integration DEBUG: Working in '/home/pi/volttron/eplus/building1'
2021-06-21 17:45:03,006 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) integrations.energyplus_integration DEBUG: Running: cd /home/pi/volttron/eplus/building1; export BCVTB_HOME=/home/pi/volttron/bcvtb; energyplus -w /home/pi/volttron/eplus/USA_WA_Pasco-Tri.Cities.AP.727845_TMY3.epw -r /home/pi/volttron/eplus/building1/BUILDING1.idf
2021-06-21 17:45:03,468 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) <stderr> ERROR: /bin/sh: 1: energyplus: Exec format error
2021-06-21 17:45:03,473 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) integrations.energyplus_integration DEBUG: Starting socket server
2021-06-21 17:45:03,473 (energyplusagent-0.1 2042) integrations.energyplus_integration DEBUG: server now listening
2021-06-21 17:45:04,591 () volttron.platform.auth WARNING: Attempt 1 to get peerlist failed with exception 0.5 seconds
2021-06-21 17:45:04,592 () volttron.platform.auth WARNING: Get list of peers from subsystem directly
2021-06-21 17:45:04,601 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: auth file /home/pi/.volttron/auth.json loaded
2021-06-21 17:45:07,434 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: AUTH: After authenticate user id: control.connection, b'd6df7a99-8bdc-4baa-8365-99e850fc31ee'
2021-06-21 17:45:07,434 () volttron.platform.auth INFO: authentication success: userid=b'd6df7a99-8bdc-4baa-8365-99e850fc31ee' domain='vip', address='localhost:1000:1000:2053', mechanism='CURVE', credentials=['ovpetUz6u_RkmcH433-2z37iZldQeWMU_F_SbLv1UGI'], user='control.connection'
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be due to running EnergyPlus on Raspberry Pi ARM.  Can you reinstall EnergyPlus using these instructions:

https://github.com/muhaftab/energyplus_rpi

Comment: Yes I am running on Raspberry.
Will check this link and update. 

Thanks

Comment: Now I followed the steps mentioned in - https://github.com/muhaftab/energyplus_rpi 
When I am trying to install Energy Plus i.e sudo checkinstall  then I am getting an error.


Enter a number to change any of them or press ENTER to continue: 

Installing with make install...

========================= Installation results ===========================
make: *** [Makefile:350: cmake_check_build_system] Segmentation fault

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.

Comment: This is the segmentation fault I got.-
https://imgur.com/a/tgivsjz